# Polymer Core-List Demo To Dart Code

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I've converted the polymer core elements demo code for core-list but, it seems the selection functionality does not work.

On the below link's source code, it has methods "selected" and "tokenList", but I cannot find these methods in the java script code.

[Polymer - Core Elements - Core List](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-elements/demo.html#core-list)

On dart however, I just added those two fields on my Object, but did not write anything aside from that. It rendered but the selection function is not working.

Any ideas how to properly convert the above link to dart code?

Dart HTML

```dart
<core-list-dart id="list" data="{{listPerson}}" height="80">
  <template>
    <div class="item {{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">
      <div class="message">
        <span class="lastname">{{lastName}}</span>
        <span class="firstname">{{firstName}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</core-list-dart>
```

Dart Class

```dart
final List<Person> listPerson = toObservable([]);
```

Class Person

```dart
class Person {
  String firstName, lastName;
  bool selected;
  var tokenList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried if it works but there are `core-list-dart` examples here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples/tree/master/web/core_list_dart

Comment: The examples are now located here: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples